# How to active submit button on keyup event if there's FileReader()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, filereader

before
i made this Javascript code for textarea onkeyup  disable/active submit form button

with below code

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-sub').attr('disabled',true);
    $('#message').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0)
            $('.btn-sub').attr('disabled', false);           
        else
            $('.btn-sub').attr('disabled',true);
    })
});
```

everything fine until here,

**But** when i used it for HTML input (file) has a FileReader() it's not working submit button keep as disabled
with below code

```js
function readURL(input) {
  var id = $(input).attr("id");

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .upload-icon').css("border", "none");
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .editit').hide();
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .prev').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("input[id^='upload_image']").change(function() {
  readURL(this);
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group border-bottom pb-3 text-center imgx">
<label class="text-center" for="upload_image" style="cursor:pointer">
    <div class="upload-icon">
        <div class="position-relative">
     <div class="editit position-absolute"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></div>
    <img class="prev" src="xx"/>
  </div>
 </div>
   </label>
  <input name="upload_image" id="upload_image" type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg text-right"  autocomplete="off">
  </div>
```

code any one help me figure out how to check if FileReader() has a value to make submit button active?

thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reader.result` to check if there is file inside the `FileReader`

```js
var reader = new FileReader();

function readURL(input) {
  var id = $(input).attr("id");

  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .upload-icon').css("border", "none");
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .editit').hide();
      $('label[for="' + id + '"] .prev').attr('src', e.target.result).show();
      validate();
    }

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

  }
}

function validate() {
  if (reader.result)
    $('.btn-sub').attr('disabled', false);
  else
    $('.btn-sub').attr('disabled', true);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-sub').attr('disabled', true);

  $("input[id^='upload_image']").change(function() {
    readURL(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group border-bottom pb-3 text-center imgx">
  <label class="text-center" for="upload_image" style="cursor:pointer">
            <div class="upload-icon">
                <div class="position-relative">
                    <div class="editit position-absolute"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></div>
                    <img class="prev" src="xx" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
  <input name="upload_image" id="upload_image" type="file" class="form-control form-control-lg text-right" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<input name="message" id="message" type="text">
<button class="btn-sub">SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: thank you very much , but i don't it for input text i want it only for the image if filereader has value submit button active

Comment: In that case, just remove the `$("#message").val().length != 0 &&` part from the `validate` function and remove the `validate` call on message change. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much, im sure much people facing this issue while using FileReader(). again thank you .